# Program freezes on input of code

Tags: java

This program works fine until I introduce the following code to it:
It's basically a long way to catch duplicates for my random number generator because I'm not to advanced at Java yet. I've heard about arraylists and collections.shuffle but they're too advanced for me. Anyway, why does my program freeze when I click the button that activates this code?

```
do {
    if (BArray[1] == BArray[0]){
        BArray[1] = 1 + bNumber.nextInt(15);
    }
    if (BArray[2] == BArray[1] || BArray[2] == BArray[0]) {
        BArray[2] = 1 + bNumber.nextInt(15);
    }
    if (BArray[3] == BArray[2] || BArray[3] == BArray[1] || BArray[3] == BArray[0]){
        BArray[3] = 1 + bNumber.nextInt(15);
    } 
    if (BArray[4] == BArray[3] || BArray[4] == BArray[2] || BArray[4] == BArray[1] || BArray [4] == BArray[0])
        BArray[4] = 1 + bNumber.nextInt(15);
} while (BArray[4] != BArray[3] || BArray[4] != BArray[2] || 
         BArray[4] != BArray[1] || BArray[4] != BArray[0] || 
         BArray[3] != BArray[2] || BArray[3] != BArray[1] || 
         BArray[3] != BArray[0] || BArray[2] != BArray[1] || 
         BArray[2] != BArray[0] || BArray[1] != BArray[0]);
```

Comment: Check your loop before you wreck yourself.

Comment: The coding seems fine to me idk what your talking about..? any hints?

Comment: Please, don't CRY AT US! Writing in CAPS only is considered impolite on SO... Instead, try to explain your problem and the steps you took to solve it!

Comment: I'm not crying just asking for help/advice.. is it that hard

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderVogt, you do yourself a disservice by expressing frustration rather than just focusing on asking your question and formatting your code neatly. It's distracting and puts off a lot of people, and is probably the reason four people downvoted you. Take a look at the edited version. There's nothing lost in terms of getting your question across, but it's easier to read and doesn't annoy anyone. Readers just need to know what the problem is, not how frustrated you are about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some exceptionally verbose code, but it is easy to see why the loop never terminates. It's clear you want to stop when there are no duplicate numbers, however, your current implementation keeps going as long as there are any different numbers. In fact, for the loop to terminate *all the numbers must be equal*.

I'm assuming what you really want is:

```
while (BArray[4] == BArray[3] || ... || BArray[1] == BArray[0]);
```

Now, a better way to accomplish this would be to use more loops!

```
bool hasDuplicates = false;

for (int i = 0; i < BArray.length; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < BArray.length; j++)
        hasDuplicates |= BArray[i] == BArray[j];

...
```

Comment: I changed all the != to == in the while statement and the game still froze

Comment: Then `1 + bNumber.nextInt(15)` is probably not changing the value. Try running the debugger/putting print statements inside the loop to see how the values change.

Comment: NVM I wrote stuff in the middle trying to fix it than i reverted back to normal with the stuff still included>

Anyways you were right my bad